# Make a single line of text bold in Mail message using Automator?

Tags: mail.app, automator, font

I have an automator script that creates a new email using the Mail app.

In this message, I would like a single line in bold as seen here:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set clipContent to (the clipboard as text)
    tell application "Mail"
        set myMessage to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"subject"}
        tell myMessage to make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:"email@email.com"}
        set myMessage's content to "

Line of text

" & clipContent & "

Line of text <---- I want this line in **BOLD**

 
Regards,
Name"
    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is one way of achieving your goal:

```applescript
set clipContent to (the clipboard as text)

set lineOfBoldText to "Line of text <---- I want this line in **BOLD**"

set myContent to linefeed & "Line of text" & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
    clipContent & linefeed & linefeed & linefeed & lineOfBoldText & ¬
    linefeed & linefeed & linefeed & "Regards," & linefeed & "Name"

set x to offset of lineOfBoldText in myContent
set y to x + (length of lineOfBoldText)

tell application "Mail"
    set myMessage to make new outgoing message at ¬
        the end of outgoing messages with properties ¬
        {subject:"subject", content:myContent}
    tell myMessage
        make new to recipient at ¬
            end of to recipients with properties ¬
            {address:"email@email.com"}
        set font of characters x thru y to "Helvetica Bold"
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Having copied to the *clipboard* "In this message, I would like a single line in bold as seen here:" from your OP and run the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown in my answer, in **Script Editor**, here is a screen shot of the results:

[image]